# php multiple array session delete

Tags: php, session, product

Temporary registration number of products that I have a session and only post in this sequence to close the session according to the number of items I want to delete, and then only

```
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 9 [stock] => 20 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 8 [stock] => 30 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 7 [stock] => 26 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 6 [stock] => 42 ) 
    )
```

In this way I tried, but did not

```
foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $item) 
        {
         if($item['product_id'] == $product_id){
                unset($item['item']['product_id']);
             }


        }
```

Comment: tried `unset($_SESSION['item']['item']['product_id']);` or `unset($_SESSION['item']['product_id']);`?

Comment: Your array seems to be of type "int", you might be working your way is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $key => $value) {
  if($value['product_id'] == $product_id) {
    unset($_SESSION['item'][$key]);
    break;
  }
}
```